# Retrieve users image from Google+ API. (App. Engine - Java)

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, google-plus

I'm trying to retrieve the google plus profile image of the user who connects to my app, so I tried something like this.

```
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

    String userMail = user.getEmail();
    String userId = user.getUserId();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();     

    List<String> serviceAccountScopes = new ArrayList<String>();

    serviceAccountScopes.add(PlusScopes.USERINFO_EMAIL);
    serviceAccountScopes.add(PlusScopes.USERINFO_PROFILE);


    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();


    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("client_secrets.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(serviceAccountScopes).build();



    Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("1078451758443-aijgd9j5p8jqd30cuta8fbtgebaq5t4f.apps.googleusercontent.com").build();

    Person person = plus.people().get(userId).execute();
    String avatar = person.getImage().getUrl();

    session.setAttribute("userMail", userMail);
    session.setAttribute("userID", userId);
    session.setAttribute("avatar", avatar);
```

But when i tried this with my google account I get an 404. So I debuged it, and I found that the value of the userId it give to me is not the same that the one in my G+ account.

The value that user.getUserId() gives me is "11879128221240184894", and the real one from my G+ account is "113502398666410404252".

So then i tried:

```
Person person = plus.people().get("113502398666410404252").execute();
```

it worked fine.

My questions are: Which is the difference between this two "userId's"? And how can I get the userId of the connected user to make it works?

Thanks in advance.